# Can you displace vehicles with explosions?

Tags: halo-4

Do vehicles get moved by plasma cannons, grenades, or any other blasts? I'm only looking for explosions made by guns.

Answer (score 2):

All vehicles can be moved (and potentially destroyed) by any type of explosion: weapons (such as rockets), grenades, tanks, etc.

I should note that there can be a fine line between moving a vehicle from an explosion and destroying it, but I'm not exactly sure what your question is.

Comment: @MyTreeko78255 You can thank me by accepting my answer.